# jhipster - how to load data from a database and show data?

Tags: jhipster

I'm learning JHipster and a beginner (web developper).

Can someone show me step by step for loading data in a database (h2 or mysql or oracle) within JHipster application and showing to the home page?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

First, you should look at the jhipster documentation to generate an app : see this [12 minute video tutorial](https://jhipster.github.io/video-tutorial/)

Jhipster actually does a lot for you, it generates the back-end with your classes, logging, database interfacing ... But also creates a nice-looking front-end for you.

Next you should have a database up and running. In the choices you have mentioned, I think Mysql could be the most interesting for a beginner as you would have a good visibility on your database (h2 is mostly in memory, I use it for testing on my app) and the install should be simple enough.
In order to do that, you could use docker or install it manually.

For docker, you just have to type the following command :

```
docker run  -p 3306:3306 --name mysql_instance_01 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -d mysql
```

And then if you want to stop it :

```
docker stop mysql_instance_01
```

See the docker documentation for more information about install and usage : [this link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/)

To connect and administrate your database graphically, you can use *dbeaver*, it is free and easy to use.

Once you have generated the app and the database is running, you have different options : either you add your 'entities' and manually populate your database, or you create an SQL script to do it for you (Which is specific to the database you're using).
JHipster is using *liquibase* which will automatically translate the entities created in Jhipster into your database.

This is a short introduction, I strongly advise you read the jhipster documentation. For example, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzdjP3CPOCs) shows what Jhipster can do and how to use it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I succeed to add a manual entity to the blog Jhipster application.

Comment: Good to know, don't hesitate to file a bug on github if you encounter a serious unsolvable problem. Always check official documentation first, it can be of great help. Have fun with jhipster !

Comment: Don't forget to validate the answer for future users who may encounter that problem. Your question will have more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this [link](http://juanlopez.com.ar/micro-servicios-con-jhipster/), a basic jhipster example